# VS2017 message: publishing to the selected azure virtual machine has not been enabled

Tags: visual-studio-2017, azure-virtual-machine, microsoft-web-deploy, visual-studio-2017-build-tools, webdeploy-3.5

I am looking for help on how to resolve the following informational message when creating a publish profile in visual studio 2017:  "publishing to the selected azure virtual machine has not been enabled".

I'm trying to set up a new publish profile for my production server.  I have already successfully set one up for my development server.  Both servers are Azure VMs.  They use different network security groups.

I get this message when selecting New Profile->Azure Virtual Machines (click browse), selecting my production server and clicking OK.

[VS2017 Production Azure VM Selected](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mjcGK.png)

I have already triple checked my firewall settings on both the VMs and Azure Portal.  I don't think these are the cause though because I do not get this message when I choose my db server which doesn't even have IIS set up.  My db and production server share an Azure network security resource group.

I'm using VS Community 2017 15.9.2 with an Azure VM and WebDeploy 3.5

C:\inetpub\logs\wmsvc has no logs on my production server but DOES have logs on my development server which makes sense since it's working there.

I tried the "Import Profile" button which seemed promising but get the following message when I click the, "Validate Connection" button:

"Could not connect to the remote computer......ERROR_DESTINATION_NOT_REACHABLE".

I've tried the following references:

https://github.com/aspnet/Tooling/blob/AspNetVMs/docs/create-asp-net-vm-with-webdeploy.md#SetupDNSName

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/install/installing-publishing-technologies/installing-and-configuring-web-deploy-on-iis-80-or-later

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/apps/cd/deploy-webdeploy-iis-deploygroups?view=vsts

https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/webdev/2017/11/01/publishing-a-web-app-to-an-azure-vm-from-visual-studio/

https://blog.tallan.com/2017/05/02/deploying-a-site-to-an-azure-vm-using-web-deploy/

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/resource-manager-common-deployment-errors

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/resource-manager-deployment-operations

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was that the production server is behind a load balancer.  The request to port 8172 was stopped there.  The solution was to add an inbound NAT rule (LoadBalancer - Inbound NAT rules) so that any attempt at the load balancer IP on 8172 gets forwarded to the production server.